# How to redraw the recycler view items residing inside a fragment on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, device-orientation

I need to redraw the entire recycler **view** items when the device orientation changes. The **recycler** view resides inside a fragment. I tried to notify the fragment about orientation change through an interface and tried to call **notifyDataSetChanged** which resulted in a

> java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

What is the ideal way to do this?

Comment: Please share your code and the full logcat. How do you understand the orientation change? Have you used `onConfigurationChange`?

Comment: In the activities onConfigurationChange I make a call to the fragment through an interface where i call notifyDataSetChanged on the recyclerviews adapter.